# webview not showing on full Screen of iphone 6

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uiwebview, ios6.0

I am new in iOS development and want to show the WebView on fullscreen, it is showing on fullscreen in iPhone5 but not in iPhone6.  it comes on half of the screen
plz take a look at https://www.dropbox.com/s/0o7b8l3o52d8623/Screen%20Shot%202014-12-31%20at%202.33.00%20pm.png?dl=0

Comment: THis problem may occur for a lot of reasons. Share what you did so that we can understand whats wrong.

Comment: My initial thoughts would be to do with sizing. If you have explicitly set the webviews size, this will cause issues

Comment: i am using autolayout
plz take a look at this
https://www.dropbox.com/s/0o7b8l3o52d8623/Screen%20Shot%202014-12-31%20at%202.33.00%20pm.png?dl=0

Comment: Unable to open links...

Comment: How are you creating your constraints? It looks to me like it's the right size for an iPhone 5 screen, so I'm guessing you have your XIBs sized to that in Interface Builder and that you *don't* have constraints that would "pull" the right and bottom edges to fill the screen. Please provide more detail.

Comment: i hv not enough reputation on stackoverflow to attach the image,
what should i do to send the snaps

Comment: i am using storyboard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Muhammad Naveed Akram Set Your View to Autolayout.

And another method to Set Constrain like as and Dislike Use AutoLayoutButton.

```
self.webView.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
```

And if You Using Custom Tool Bar then Set  Autosizing For WebView like as

For WebView

[image]

For ToolBar

[image]

Hope it Helps You.

Comment: by doing this , webview comes on full screen but the tool bar vanished

Comment: @Muhammad Naveed Akram you use Custum ToolBar?

Comment: yes i am using custum tool bar and adding button on that just shown in above link

Comment: @Muhammad Naveed Akram see my Updated Answer.